# Is it wrong to use "more X than Y" structure before verbs?

Tags: comparative-constructions

Is it wrong to use more.. than structure before verbs?

For example :

> They more talk than work.
>
> This product has been more produced than consumed.
>
> I want to more take action than make plans.
>
> I like more reading books than watching TV

Comment: The only one of your examples which is grammatical is #2, though the actual example is not a particularly good one, since we would not say there was oversupply in that manner. They talk more than (they) work. I want to take action more than make plans.  I like reading books more than watching TV.  You can substitute **prefer**.  I prefer reading books to watching TV. I prefer taking action over making plans.

Comment: This is a good question.  Mostly I I don't think we use this structure with verbs, but I can imagine saying something like: *He ran right over - well, more "walked" than "ran".*  But that's kind of a special case.

Comment: I'd say 'I like reading books more than watching TV.'

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to give some insights to the construct. In a colloquial sense, some of these may be uttered in practice, but the corrected form are as follows.

> 1. They talk more than they work
> 2. The product has been produced more than it is consumed
> 3. I want to take more actions than to make plans
> 4. I like reading more books than watching TV.

When used along with a sentence in such as the above *"more...than"* does not come in the way you construct it to be.

Phrased in an active (but slightly different) way, example 2 can be written as

> The company produces more products than it can sell

The word *'sell'* would refer to the consumption by customers

If the verb for both instances connected with 'more' and 'than' are the same, then you might get something like this:

> 1. They talk more Spanish than English
> 2. The company produce more furniture than appliances
> 3. I want to do more action than planning
> 4. I like reading more than watching

In all cases, 'more' appears only *after* the verb.

Comment: I agree with your answer save for your wording for #3; I see that one as: _I want to take action more than make plans._

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for your kind suggestion; you may make the edit to the answer as you please.